# Query post order by post and desc not working

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, meta-value

I have a query that displays post the order of the post 1 to 10
and front-end added:  `<?php print intval( $post->menu_order );?>º` there shows 1º, 2º, 3º ... 10º

must reverse the display but keep the number of order to stay well
10º, 9º ... 1º

The post number 1, will remain the 1º but should appear at the end. 
I do not know how to do this work :(

and not work for me with 'orderby = > 'DESC'

Any idea?

my code:

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>'ranking')); ?>
            <?php $mypost = array( 
                'post_type' => 'ranking',
                'orderby' => 'post',                                     
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'meta_key'    => 'top10',
                'meta_value'    => 'sim'
                     );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost ); ?>
            <!-- Cycle through all posts -->
            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
             content format one...
```

and it continues on the same page 11 to 50 whith:

```
 <?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>'ranking')); ?>
            <?php $mypost = array( 
                'post_type' => 'ranking', 
                'orderby' => 'post',                  
                'showposts' => -1 ,
                'meta_key'    => 'top10',
                'meta_value'    => 'nao'               
                 );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost ); ?>
            <!-- Cycle through all posts -->
            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?> 
            content format two...
```

Comment: You should ***never*** use `query_posts`, use either `WP_Query`, or if you're modifying the main loop, use the `pre_get_posts` filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`post` is not a valid value for `orderby` parameter neither `DESC`. You can choose [any of these values](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). Also, you should stop using `query_post`.

```
<?php
$args = array( 
            'post_type'      => 'ranking',
            'orderby'        => 'menu_order', 
            'order'          => 'DESC',                                    
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'meta_key'       => 'top10',
            'meta_value'     => 'sim'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
     $loop->the_post();
     //Do whatever you want with the posts
}
//After the loop reset post data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```